# Table [Row] cannot be deleted using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am having trouble deleting the row off the table using the button.

Live: http://jsfiddle.net/Z7fG7/21/

HTML:

```
<select class="combobox form-control">
    <option value="" selected="selected">Choose a Person</option>
    <option>Bob</option>
    <option>Kyle</option>
</select>
<br>


<!-- Table -->
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <div class="container">
            <tr>
                <th>First Last Name</th>
            </tr>
        </div>
    </thead>
</table>
```

JS/Jquery:

```
$('.combobox').change(function(e) {

   var selectedVal = $(this).val();
   $('.table').append('<tr><td>' + selectedVal + '</td><td><img class="delete" src="images/delete.png" width="25" height="25"/></td></tr>');

});

$('table td img.delete').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
});
```

I am using Bootstrap. Any help would be great!

Comment: What is the problem ? From what I see, it seems to work fine nah ?

Comment: [**Delegated event handlers for dynamically created elements**](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Comment: Why have you got a `<div>` nested inside of a `<thead>`? I'm pretty sure that's invalid HTML.

Comment: @ddr2 Opps, posted the wrong link.

Comment: @bensingh: Your answers are already there below :) It is a problem of attaching event handlers to dynamically created events. For such cases you have to attach the event handler using the closest static parent element (say like `$('table').on('click', 'td img.delete', function(){`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The click handler for the delete image has to be added to every new row in the table.

```js
$('.combobox').change(function(e) {

   var selectedVal = $(this).val();
   $('.table').append('<tr><td>' + selectedVal + '</td><td><img class="delete" src="images/delete.png" width="25" height="25"/></td></tr>');
   $('table td img.delete').click(function(){
       $(this).parent().parent().remove();
   });

});
```

Comment: That's just horrible, it would add the event handler over and over again to all existing `.delete` elements ?

Comment: @adeneo is right of course! You should add the handler only once for each element.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look into delegated events http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/robschmuecker/Z7fG7/20/

```
 var i = 1;
 $("#addbutton").click(function () {
     $("table tr:first").clone().find("input").each(function () {
         $(this).val('').attr({
             'id': function (_, id) {
                 return id + i
             },
                 'name': function (_, name) {
                 return name + i
             },
                 'value': ''
         });
     }).end().appendTo("table");
     i++;
 });

 $(document).on('click', 'button.removebutton', function () {
     alert("aa");
     $(this).closest('tr').remove();
     return false;
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Or, in addition to above, when you use .clone by default it remove all events. A cleaner answer using your existing code:

EDIT: Forgot to explain! Using .clone(true) keeps the events. Your .on function is working correctly without needing to reapply it on each new row too.

```
var i = 1;
$("#addbutton").click(function() {
$("table tr:first").clone(true).find("input").each(function() {
$(this).val('').attr({
  'id': function(_, id) {return id + i },
  'name': function(_, name) { return name + i },
  'value': ''               
});
}).end().appendTo("table");
  i++;

});

$('button.removebutton').on('click', function() {
    alert("aa");
  $(this).closest( 'tr').remove();
  return false;
});
```